# Way to center a grid of images in CSS/HTML?

Tags: html, css, image, center

I'm trying to figure out a way to center the photo grid that I have on the following page of my website:

http://www.thefloodplains.com/Gallery

As you can see, all of the gridded content seems to float to the left automatically, while I want it to remain in the center and have the page be symmetrical.

Here's my CSS:

```
h2 {
    color: #FF8B6F;
    text-decoration-color: #FF8B6F;
    font-size: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
}
h1 {
    font-size: 50px;
    font-family: 'Buenard', Garamond, 'EB Garamond', Georgia;
    color: #00A5D1;
    padding-bottom: -1px;
}
h {
    font-family: 'Buenard', Garamond, 'EB Garamond', Georgia;
    font-size: 32px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-align: center;
    }
p  {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 2px;
    }
p2 {
    font-size: 22px;
    margin-top: 1px;
    color: #00A5D1;
    }
div.containercenter {
    margin: 0px auto;
    align-content: center;
    margin-left: 58px; 
}    
hr {
    border: none;
    height: 2px;
    color: black;
    background-color: #FFE097;
    margin: 20px 0 20px 0;  
    padding: 4px;
}
.pad {
    margin-bottom: 2px;
    padding-bottom: 2px;
}    
/* Create four equal columns that floats next to each other */
.column {
    float: left;
    width: 23%;
    padding: 8px;
    margin-top: -22px;
}

.column img {
    margin-top: 12px;
    margin-bottom: 6px;
    width: 100%;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */
.row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

/* Responsive layout - makes a two column-layout instead of four columns */
@media (max-width: 800px) {
    .column {
        width: 50%;
    }
}

/* Responsive layout - makes the two columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
@media (max-width: 600px) {
    .column {
        width: 100%;
   }
}

/* adding the menu bar */

div.pad {
    padding-bottom: 24px;    
    }   

a.none {
        text-decoration: none;
        border-bottom: none;}      

.fullwidth {
    max-width: 960px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    }     

ul.topnav {
    list-style-type: none;
    list-style:none;
    text-align:center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Buenard', Garamond, 'EB Garamond', Georgia, serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    overflow: hidden;
    opacity: 0.7;
    /* background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85); */
    background-color: none;
}
ul.topnav li {display: inline;}

ul.topnav li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #FF8B6F;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0px 0px;
    padding: 15px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.topnav-centered a {
  float: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

ul.topnav li a:hover:not(.active) {background-color: #00A5D1;}

ul.topnav li a.active {background-color: #00A5D1;}

ul.topnav li.left {float: left;}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px){
    ul.topnav li.right, 
    ul.topnav li {float: none;}
    ul.topnav li.left {float: none;}
}          

/* adding the menu bar */

div.pad {
    padding-bottom: 24px;    
    }   

a.none {
        text-decoration: none;
        border-bottom: none;}      

.fullwidth {
    max-width: 960px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    }     

ul.topnav {
    list-style-type: none;
    list-style:none;
    text-align:center;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Buenard', Garamond, 'EB Garamond', Georgia, serif;
    font-weight: 700;
    overflow: hidden;
    opacity: 0.7;
    /* background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.85); */
    background-color: none;
}
ul.topnav li {display: inline;}

ul.topnav li a {
    display: inline-block;
    color: #FF8B6F;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0px 0px;
    padding: 15px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.topnav-centered a {
  float: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

ul.topnav li a:hover:not(.active) {background-color: #00A5D1;}

ul.topnav li a.active {background-color: #00A5D1;}

ul.topnav li.left {float: left;}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px){
    ul.topnav li.right, 
    ul.topnav li {float: none;}
    ul.topnav li.left {float: none;}
}
```

And here's the HTML in question:

```
<!-- Photo Grid -->
<div class="row"> 
<!-- <div class="containercenter"> -->
  <div class="column">
    <h2><center>Albums</center></h>
    <img src="http://www.thegrassrootsgarage.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Let-Loose-the-Floodgates.png" style="width:100%">
      <center><p2>Let Loose the Floodgates</p2></center>
    <img src="http://www.thegrassrootsgarage.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/Split-Artwork.jpg" style="width:100%">
      <center><p2>TYSFC / The FloodShark Split</p2></center>
    <img src="AnotherWilliamBlake.jpg" style="width:100%">
        <center><p2>Another William Blake</p2></center>

  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <h2><center>EPs</center></h>
    <img src="http://www.thegrassrootsgarage.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Synthetic-Shark-Album-Art.png" style="width:100%">
        <center><p2>Synthetic Shark</p2></center>
    <img src="http://www.thegrassrootsgarage.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/The-Black-Butterfly.png" style="width:100%">
        <center><p2>The Black Butterfly</p2></center>

  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <h2><center>Singles</center></h>
    <img src="http://www.thegrassrootsgarage.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/HungryShark2-Alteration-2.jpg" style="width:100%">
        <center><p2>HungryShark</p2></center>
    <img src="HungrySharkSpotify.jpg" style="width:100%">
        <center><p2>HungryShark Alt</p2></center>  
    <img src="http://www.thegrassrootsgarage.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/The-Man-on-the-Porch-TGrG-cover.jpg" style="width:100%">
        <center><p2>The Man on the Porch</p2></center>
    <img src="http://www.thegrassrootsgarage.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/Sentimental-Shark-Art-Final-Art-Original.jpg" style="width:100%">
        <center><p2>Sentimental Shark</p2></center>
    <img src="http://www.thegrassrootsgarage.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/Sentimental-Shark-Art-cropped.jpg" style="width:100%">
        <center><p2>Sentimental Shark OG</p2></center>
    <img src="Kai.png" style="width:100%">
        <center><p2>Kai (rereleased)</p2></center>
    <img src="ComeWavesArt1.png" style="width:100%">
        <center><p2>Come Waves (rereleased)</p2></center>
    <img src="LasLuces2.png" style="width:100%">
        <center><p2>Las Luces</p2></center>
    <img src="LasLuces3.png" style="width:100%">
        <center><p2>Las Luces alt</p2></center>  

  </div>
    <div class="column">
    <h2><center>Logos / Misc</center></h>
    <img src="http://www.thegrassrootsgarage.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/Logo-1.jpeg">
        <center><p2>Shark Cans Classic</p2></center>
    <img src="http://www.thegrassrootsgarage.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/Shark-Logo-2.jpg">
        <center><p2>Shades of a Shark 1</p2></center>
    <img src="http://www.thegrassrootsgarage.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/Shark-Logo-2-Alt-1.jpg">
        <center><p2>Shades of a Shark 2</p2></center>
    <img src="http://www.thegrassrootsgarage.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/Shark-Logo-alt-6-green-sharpened.jpg">
        <center><p2>Shades of a Shark Green</p2></center>
    <img src="http://www.thegrassrootsgarage.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/Shark-Logo-alt-5-pink.jpg">
        <center><p2>Shades of a Shark Pink</p2></center>
    <img src="FloodSharkLogo2018.png">
        <center><p2>Shark Cans 2018</p2></center>    
    </div>
</div>
```

I've tried simple fixes like  and even "margin: 0" type of solutions, but nothing has worked yet. I even added padding on the left side to make it seem symmetrical on my PC screen, but then it ends up looking much worse on mobile and other screens. It seems like an easy fix, but I haven't been able to find the right solution. I just need to center to the photo grid.

Any and all help would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Instead of floats look into css flexbox. i think that will work very well in this situation. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ so in your case .row {display:flex; justify-content:space-between;} and remove float:left from .column

Comment: To be honest -- loading your website, the images load slow as f\*\*k . I would ***highly*** recommend optimising your images. 1Mb is **far too much** for one 800x800px image. This should be maybe 100kb max; look up [image optimisation](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/image-optimization)

Comment: Plus mobile data users will **NOT** appreciate having to spend ~5-10MB to simply load your frontpage. C'mon.....

Comment: *And* (sorry, more criticism) you really should be using a secured connection. Get a [Lets Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/getting-started/) certificate and join the Safer Web of 2018. It's free.

Comment: Thanks for the constructive criticism. That's why I'm here! Going to look into everything that's been mentioned, thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, there are a lot of things to say:

- There are a lot of `</h>` to check, i think there are a typo but please check before post
- You should avoid `<center>`, it's deprecated and not supported in html5, [check W3 documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/Tags/tag_center.asp)
- You should use a lot of headings instead of `<p2>`
- Try to avoid inline style in `img` you can stilish them in css

Now, you can actually use grid for your project.
In my example i wrapped the `h4` and `img` in div.

I splitted the `.row` in 4 columns, using the `fr` unit: `1fr` is 1 part of the available space, with a grid gap of 2% and `align-items: start` (in this way all the column element starts from the top).

Every inner `.column` have the first row (h1) declared and the other with: `grid-auto-rows:300px` so every grid will have a full height of 300px.

Every inner `img` is set to `place-self: center` and every `h4` is set to `place-self: end center` (first value for the X axis, second for Y.) In this way all the `h4` are set at the bottom of the cell.

For the responsive version, i've set the `.row` to only 2 separate `fr` for a two column result.

You can find the most complete guide of grid layout [here](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/).

Here's the code.

```css
h1 {
    font-size: 50px;
    font-family: 'Buenard', Garamond, 'EB Garamond', Georgia;
    color: #00A5D1;
}
h2 {
    color: #FF8B6F;
    font-size: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    text-align: center;
}
h4 {
    font-size: 22px;
    margin-top: 1px;
    color: #00A5D1;
    text-align: center;
}  

.row{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 2%;
  align-items: start;
}

.column{
  display: grid;
  justify-items: center;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-auto-rows: 300px;
}

.column div{
  display: grid;
}

.column img{
  place-self: center;
}

.column div h4{
  place-self: end center;
}





.column img {
    height: 75%;
}

/* Clear floats after the columns */


/* Responsive layout - makes a two column-layout instead of four columns */
@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .row{
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    grid-gap: 2%;
    align-items: start;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
 <div class="column">
  <h2>Albums</h2>
  <div>
   <img src="http://www.thegrassrootsgarage.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Let-Loose-the-Floodgates.png">
   <h4>Let Loose the Floodgates</h4>
  </div>
  <div>
   <img src="http://www.thegrassrootsgarage.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/Split-Artwork.jpg">
   <h4>TYSFC / The FloodShark Split</h4>
  </div>
  <div>
   <img src="AnotherWilliamBlake.jpg">
   <h4>Another William Blake</h4>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="column">
  <h2>EPs</h2>
  <div>
   <img src="http://www.thegrassrootsgarage.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Synthetic-Shark-Album-Art.png">
   <h4>Synthetic Shark</h4>
  </div>
  <div>
   <img src="http://www.thegrassrootsgarage.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/The-Black-Butterfly.png">
   <h4>The Black Butterfly</h4>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="column">
  <h2>Singles</h2>
  <div>
   <img src="http://www.thegrassrootsgarage.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/HungryShark2-Alteration-2.jpg">
   <h4>HungryShark</h4>
  </div>
  <div>
   <img src="HungrySharkSpotify.jpg">
   <h4>HungryShark Alt</h4>
  </div>
  <div>
   <img src="http://www.thegrassrootsgarage.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/The-Man-on-the-Porch-TGrG-cover.jpg">
   <h4>The Man on the Porch</h4>
  </div>
  <div>
   <img src="http://www.thegrassrootsgarage.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/Sentimental-Shark-Art-Final-Art-Original.jpg">
   <h4>Sentimental Shark</h4>
  </div>
  <div>
   <img src="http://www.thegrassrootsgarage.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/Sentimental-Shark-Art-cropped.jpg">
   <h4>Sentimental Shark OG</h4>
  </div>
  <div>
   <img src="Kai.png">
   <h4>Kai (rereleased)</h4>
  </div>
  <div>
   <img src="ComeWavesArt1.png">
   <h4>Come Waves (rereleased)</h4>
  </div>
  <div>
   <img src="LasLuces2.png">
   <h4>Las Luces</h4>
  </div>
  <div>
   <img src="LasLuces3.png">
   <h4>Las Luces alt</h4>
  </div>
 </div>

 <div class="column">
  <h2>Logos / Misc</h2>
  <div>
   <img src="http://www.thegrassrootsgarage.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/Logo-1.jpeg">
   <h4>Shark Cans Classic</h4>
  </div>
  <div>
   <img src="http://www.thegrassrootsgarage.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/Shark-Logo-2.jpg">
   <h4>Shades of a Shark 1</h4>
  </div>
  <div>
   <img src="http://www.thegrassrootsgarage.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/Shark-Logo-2-Alt-1.jpg">
   <h4>Shades of a Shark 2</h4>
  </div>
  <div>
   <img src="http://www.thegrassrootsgarage.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/Shark-Logo-alt-6-green-sharpened.jpg">
   <h4>Shades of a Shark Green</h4>
  </div>
  <div>
   <img src="http://www.thegrassrootsgarage.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/Shark-Logo-alt-5-pink.jpg">
   <h4>Shades of a Shark Pink</h4>
  </div>
  <div>
   <img src="FloodSharkLogo2018.png">
   <h4>Shark Cans 2018</h4>
  </div>
 </div>
  
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'm currently using your code - the problem is, every time I load on my desktop the images are squished horizontally until I hover over them with my mouse, whereby they increase their width. I guess my question is, how do I prevent that, and instead just have them be full width when the page loads?

Comment: It's because of `img {height: auto; max-width: 100%;}` (main3.css - line 98), you have to remove the max-width

Comment: Awesome. Works perfectly now! Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

It is easier and cleaner to use [CSS grid](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp).

```css
html,body{
  padding: 0;
  margin:0;
}

h2 {
  color: #ff8b6f;
  -webkit-text-decoration-color: #ff8b6f;
          text-decoration-color: #ff8b6f;
  font-size: 40px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
}

h1 {
  font-size: 50px;
  font-family: "Buenard", Garamond, "EB Garamond", Georgia;
  color: #00a5d1;
  padding-bottom: -1px;
}

h {
  font-family: "Buenard", Garamond, "EB Garamond", Georgia;
  font-size: 32px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-align: center;
}

p {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 2px;
}

p2 {
  font-size: 22px;
  margin-top: 1px;
  color: #00a5d1;
}

hr {
  border: none;
  height: 2px;
  color: black;
  background-color: #ffe097;
  margin: 20px 0 20px 0;
  padding: 4px;
}

.row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 25%); //4 columns each row with a width of 25%
  grid-gap: 8px;
}

.column img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -o-object-fit: cover;
     object-fit: cover;
  margin-top: 12px;
  margin-bottom: 6px;
}

/* Responsive layout - makes a two column-layout instead of four columns */
@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .row {
    grid-template-columns: auto auto; //2 columns per row while browser window is less than 800px
  }
}
/* Responsive layout - makes the two columns stack on top of each other instead of next to each other */
@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .row {
    grid-template-columns: auto; //only 1 column per row while browser window is less than 800px
  }
  }
}
```

```html
<!-- Photo Grid -->
<div class="row">
  <!-- <div class="containercenter"> -->
  <div class="column">
    <h2>
      <center>Albums</center>
      </h>
      <img src="http://www.thegrassrootsgarage.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Let-Loose-the-Floodgates.png" style="width:100%">
      <center>
        <p2>Let Loose the Floodgates</p2>
      </center>
      <img src="http://www.thegrassrootsgarage.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/08/Split-Artwork.jpg" style="width:100%">
      <center>
        <p2>TYSFC / The FloodShark Split</p2>
      </center>
      <img src="AnotherWilliamBlake.jpg" style="width:100%">
      <center>
        <p2>Another William Blake</p2>
      </center>

  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <h2>
      <center>EPs</center>
      </h>
      <img src="http://www.thegrassrootsgarage.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/Synthetic-Shark-Album-Art.png" style="width:100%">
      <center>
        <p2>Synthetic Shark</p2>
      </center>
      <img src="http://www.thegrassrootsgarage.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/The-Black-Butterfly.png" style="width:100%">
      <center>
        <p2>The Black Butterfly</p2>
      </center>

  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <h2>
      <center>Singles</center>
      </h>
      <img src="http://www.thegrassrootsgarage.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/05/HungryShark2-Alteration-2.jpg" style="width:100%">
      <center>
        <p2>HungryShark</p2>
      </center>
      <img src="HungrySharkSpotify.jpg" style="width:100%">
      <center>
        <p2>HungryShark Alt</p2>
      </center>
      <img src="http://www.thegrassrootsgarage.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/07/The-Man-on-the-Porch-TGrG-cover.jpg" style="width:100%">
      <center>
        <p2>The Man on the Porch</p2>
      </center>
      <img src="http://www.thegrassrootsgarage.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/Sentimental-Shark-Art-Final-Art-Original.jpg" style="width:100%">
      <center>
        <p2>Sentimental Shark</p2>
      </center>
      <img src="http://www.thegrassrootsgarage.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/01/Sentimental-Shark-Art-cropped.jpg" style="width:100%">
      <center>
        <p2>Sentimental Shark OG</p2>
      </center>
      <img src="Kai.png" style="width:100%">
      <center>
        <p2>Kai (rereleased)</p2>
      </center>
      <img src="ComeWavesArt1.png" style="width:100%">
      <center>
        <p2>Come Waves (rereleased)</p2>
      </center>
      <img src="LasLuces2.png" style="width:100%">
      <center>
        <p2>Las Luces</p2>
      </center>
      <img src="LasLuces3.png" style="width:100%">
      <center>
        <p2>Las Luces alt</p2>
      </center>

  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <h2>
      <center>Logos / Misc</center>
      </h>
      <img src="http://www.thegrassrootsgarage.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/Logo-1.jpeg">
      <center>
        <p2>Shark Cans Classic</p2>
      </center>
      <img src="http://www.thegrassrootsgarage.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/Shark-Logo-2.jpg">
      <center>
        <p2>Shades of a Shark 1</p2>
      </center>
      <img src="http://www.thegrassrootsgarage.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/Shark-Logo-2-Alt-1.jpg">
      <center>
        <p2>Shades of a Shark 2</p2>
      </center>
      <img src="http://www.thegrassrootsgarage.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/Shark-Logo-alt-6-green-sharpened.jpg">
      <center>
        <p2>Shades of a Shark Green</p2>
      </center>
      <img src="http://www.thegrassrootsgarage.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/12/Shark-Logo-alt-5-pink.jpg">
      <center>
        <p2>Shades of a Shark Pink</p2>
      </center>
      <img src="FloodSharkLogo2018.png">
      <center>
        <p2>Shark Cans 2018</p2>
      </center>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please explain what "grid" is and how this system works on the general level.